# How to maintain standard form with binomials such as -x + 1?

Tags: maxima

I'm using Maxima to print stuff into a web page in an educational context. Most of the time everything works smoothly, but I'm having problems with binomials such as -x + 1, which Maxima simplifies as 1 - x. I quess that this is because this form takes less characters.

But in educational context this is often not desired, as in the standard form the term with x should always be before constant.

So is there any option to prevent this kind of simplification?

I have tried using ratvars(x), totaldisrep(-x+1) and declare(x,mainvar), none of those did what I was looking for.

Outputs:

x + 1;

> x+1

x - 1;

> x-1

-x - 1;

> -x-1

-x + 1;

> 1-x

I wish to find a way to get this last one to output -x+1.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `negsumdispflag` to `false`. See: `? negsumdispflag`

I get these results, maybe this is acceptable.

```
(%i12) negsumdispflag:false;
(%o12)                        false
(%i13) x + 1;
(%o13)                        x + 1
(%i14) x - 1;
(%o14)                        x - 1
(%i15) 1 - x;
(%o15)                      (- x) + 1
(%i16) - 1 - x;
(%o16)                      (- x) - 1
```